# Fixing this undefined-function in lisp code?

Tags: recursion, syntax, lisp, common-lisp, cons

I am losing my mind over evaluating this code to find the error. I am not sure why I am getting an undefined function. Would someone please guide me to understand why? thanks!

O is supposed to be an object, and L a list. I am trying to attach O to the end of the list and return the list

```
(defun my_attach(O L)
    (cond ((eq L nil )
        O )
        (t (cons (car L) (my-attach O (cdr L)) )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `(eq x nil)` is usually written `(null x)` or `(not x)`. These are equivalent. `null` is typically used in a situation when `nil` represents the empty list; `not` is used when the `nil` is denoting a Boolean false.

Comment: A two-clause `cond` of the form `(cond (x y) (t z))`, where `x`, `y` and `z` are all single expressions, is usually written `(if x y z)`.

Comment: Avoid using `O` as an identifier in programs; it can be confused for zero.

Comment: `(defun my-attach (oh list) (if (null list) oh (cons (car list) (my-attach oh (cdr list)))))`

Comment: If we test the list for not being null and swap the two clauses, we can shorten it:  `(defun my-attach (oh list) (if list (cons (car list) (my-attach oh (cdr list))) oh))`

Answer (score 5):

If you have copied correctly your code in the post, you have used two different names for the same function: `my_attach` (_ is the underscore character) and `my-attach` (- is the dash character).

Simply use the same name. For instance:

```
(defun my-attach(O L)
  (cond ((eq L nil ) O)
        (t (cons (car L) (my-attach O (cdr L))))))
```

But note that this will not produce the desired result (in fact it does not produce a proper list). Rather, you should use `(list O)` instead of `O` in the terminal case:

```
CL-USER> (defun my-attach(O L)
           (cond ((eq L nil) O)
                 (t (cons (car L) (my-attach O (cdr L))))))
MY-ATTACH
CL-USER> (my-attach 3 '(1 2))
(1 2 . 3)
CL-USER> (my-attach 3 '())
3
CL-USER> (defun my-attach(O L)
           (cond ((eq L nil) (list O))
                 (t (cons (car L) (my-attach O (cdr L))))))
MY-ATTACH
CL-USER> (my-attach 3 '(1 2))
(1 2 3)
CL-USER> (my-attach 3 '())
(3)
```

Finally, a note about the common writing conventions for Common Lisp programs:

1. it is preferred to use lower case identifiers;
2. compound words in identifiers are separated by `-`, not by `_` as in other languages;
3. it is preferred to use `if` when there are only two cases in a conditional statement;
4. check for a value which is `nil` is commonly done with the predicate `null`;
5. the parentheses at the end of an expression are usually written on the same line of the last part of the expression.

So your function could be rewritten as:

```
(defun my-attach (o l)
  (if (null l)
      (list o)
      (cons (car l) (my-attach o (cdr l)))))
```